# Angular js Routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am a rails developer new to angular js.

In  MVC framework languages we can specify routes for an action or method in controller.
Is there any way to call a function of  controller in angular js using angular ui-router

Comment: you mean host/controllerName/methodName routing?

Comment: yes, I want routes like controller/method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't automatically fire a method by specifying correct routing, but you can manage it on your own, like this:

```
angular('app').config(function( $routeProvider ){
            $routeProvider.when("/ctrl",
                    {
                        action: "ctrl.default"
                    }
                );
});


angular('app').controller('ctrl', function($route) {
    render = function() {
        $scope.action = $route.current.action.split( "." ); 
    }

    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",function( $currentRoute, $previousRoute ){

        render();

    });
```

Basicly, event gets fired every time elements in route are changed, meanwhile in `render()` method you can work on case switching correct action for provided parameters in `$scope.action`

As you can see, the variable `action` is the one, which holds info that is passed to controller.

Above code is written without testing, so beware :p